# TypeError: Date is not a constructor (Strange)

Tags: javascript

I am working on my angular application. and I just get this strange error. I did say strange because I use this type of expression in my whole application but here I am getting this Date Constructor here? If I am wrong somewhere? please correct me!

**Console Error.**

[image]

**Actual Code Line**

[image]

Comment: That means you must be overwriting `Date`

Comment: I dont think so...i read my code...and I just need Date in this line only (396)

Comment: Try referencing it as `window.Date`. Something is definitely overwriting the standard Date class, could be a local variable within that scope or a service being instantiated in that name, double check your code

Comment: What do you get if you try `console.log(Date);` ?